# Spring Data Hibernate 6 losing data in parent object

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, aws-fargate

I'm facing a strange problem. We're searching this bug for two weeks now and have no idea why this happens.

**Let me explain the process and situation.**

We have an application that receives data and stores them in the Postgres database in status "UPLOADED".
A separate running worker picks the data in this state and works on it in a scheduled job.
The process fetches data from some other sources and adds them to the parent entity. After the data has been enriched the parent entity changes the state to "READY" and within the same process the parent entity is rated by some rules.

If the rating is ok the parent entity is "ACCEPTED" or "REJECTED", if some data is missing the parent entity remains in state "READY".
In case of ACCEPTED or REJECTED some follow up operations are started.

The whole code is running within one Transaction managed by Springs Transaction Manager

```
final var uploadedData = repository.findByStatus(ParentEntity.UPLOADED, PageRequest.of(0, 50, Sort.by("createdAt", "id").ascending())); 

uploadedData
            .forEach(parentEntity -> {
                ...
                var processedParentEntity = parentEntity;
                try {
                    processedParentEntity = transaction.execute(status -> {
                        analyze(parentEntity, retries.getOrDefault(parentEntity.getId(), 0) < maxTries);
                        return receiptRepository.findFirstById(parentEntity.getId()).get();
                    });
                 
                } catch (final TemporaryProblem temporaryProblem) {
                  ...
                } catch (final Exception exception) {
                 ...
                }
            });
        logger.info("finished parentEntity analysis");
```

The problem is that in some cases under certain conditions, the data of the parentEntity are persisted wrong although the logs say that the entity is in the correct state and has the correct data.
Every added child entity in 1..N relations is persisted correctly. No Exception occur and nothing is rolled back.

In over 99 % the data is persisted correctly but in some strange cases the parentEntity remains in status "UPLOADED" and the worker processes the entity once again which ends in follow up problems.

We can see that the problem is perhaps related to the Spring Boot 3 updated we made in May. We can see that when the problem occurs often multiple parentEntities are affected in a row and then for hours the problem doesn't occur.

The Task is running in an AWS fargate container and the DB is a managed RDS instance.
We have a lot of integration tests and by now we cannot reproduce the problem in a local environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the bug finally today.
It is a constellation where the web container and the worker query the same entity which is attached to different JVM Entity Managers.

When the web request, which is only a read request, and the commit from the worker run concurrent the entity manager of the web container detects a change and updates the complete page of fetched entities and hence he overrides the changes.

We will fix the bug with optimistic locking by adding @Version to our parent entity. Hopefully this helps us the fix the issue.

**Update**

The bug was even easier to fix. We removed a wrongly introduced @Transactional in a simple find method. This led to an update statement made on the passed entity.